# How can I target WordPress 3.8 new interface MP6 with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

When [MP6 was a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mp6/) in WordPress 3.6+ it changes the body class of the admin and added an "admin-mp6" class which helps me to style my plugin accordingly.

Now with the latest Alpha of WordPress 3.8 the class was removed. I know since it's an alpha version the class may come back but I wonder if there are any official "best practices"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Andrew Nacin](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/author/nacin/) posted some "offical" approach to this topic [here](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2013/11/19/targeting-the-new-dashboard-design-in-a-post-mp6-world/)

The CSS only variant should use the branch-3-x class to target the versions **before** 3.8 and the defaults should get applied to all upcoming versions so you don't have to care about further version:

```
.branch-3-6 .some-selector,
.branch-3-7 .some-selector {
     /* some rules go here for 3.6 and 3.7 */
}
.some-selector {
     /* 3.8+ rules go here */
}
```

[Read more about](http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2013/11/19/targeting-the-new-dashboard-design-in-a-post-mp6-world/) this topic on the make.wordpress.org page